# Length of a variable in powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-container-registry

I was writing a script to list the tags of a repository in ACR. The code was like this:

```
$RepoList = az acr repository list --name $AzureRegistryName --output tsv
Write-Host "Repos: " $RepoList.length

foreach ($RepositoryName in $RepoList) {
    Write-Host "Get all tags in repository: " $RepositoryName
    $RepositoryTags = az acr repository show-tags --name $AzureRegistryName --repository $RepositoryName --orderby time_desc --output tsv
    Write-Host "Tags: " $RepositoryTags.length
  }
```

The `$RepositoryTags.length` returned correct length, that is, the total number of tags most of the time.

But when there is only one tag in a repository, the length was not equal to actual the number of tags present.

Why does this happen? How to resolve this?

Comment: Try [Array subexpression operator @( )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#array-subexpression-operator--) as `$RepositoryTags = @(az acr repository show-tags  --name $AzureRegistryName --repository $RepositoryName --orderby time_desc --output tsv)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried printing the variable type:

```
$RepoList.getType()
$RepositoryTags.getType()
```

I noticed that when there is more than one tag available for a repository, the type of  is:

```
$RepositoryTags.getType()  

IsPublic   IsSerial     Name          BaseType                                                    
--------   --------     ----          --------  
True       True         Object[]      System.Array
```

When there is only one tag, the type is:

```
$RepositoryTags.getType() 

IsPublic   IsSerial     Name          BaseType                                                    
--------   --------     ----          --------  
True       True         String        System.Object
```

That means, in the second case, `$RepositoryTags.length` returns the length of a string (of that one tag). Obviously, that will not be equal to the number of tags available for that repository.

To solve this, get the result to an array using array sub-expression operator `@( ... )`. Change the lines as:

```
$RepoList = @(az acr repository list --name $AzureRegistryName --output tsv)

$RepositoryTags = @(az acr repository show-tags --name $AzureRegistryName --repository $RepositoryName --orderby time_desc --output tsv)
```

Now even if the number of tags is 1, the result will be treated as an array instead of a string.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `Azure` powershell module?  When using `az` from the cli, you're just getting strings back from an external program.